# Linux Subsystem for Windows cannot access the Internet

Tags: bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For some reason my Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is unable to access the Internet.

I.e. when I do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get a bunch of failed fetches. Exactly as the issue describe [under this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/5).

I have tried all of the suggest solutions, but none of them seems to work.

### Things that I have tried:

- adding `8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`,
- adding my default gateway to `/etc/resolv.conf`,
- disabling IPv6,
- running in Administrative Mode,
- uninstalling and reinstalling Bash,
- disabling my antivirus.

### Here is what my resolv.conf looks like:

```
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

Comment: You leave quite a number of questions open in your request: - When you say "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows", are you talking about a Virtual Machine (guest) running Ubuntu on a Windows host? - If so: - which virtualisation software are you using? how is the guest's network card set up? - Which Ubuntu are you running on which Windows host?

Comment: `Bash on Ubuntu on Windows` is built-in in Windows 10 Redstone build. https://msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl/install_guide

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that by "disabling my antivirus* you mean *disabling my antivirus/firewall*, beware that disabling the firewall is not always sufficient depending on the one you use. The current (unsatisfactory) workaround is to uninstall the firewall.

This and other recommendations can be found in the following post from the Linux Subsystem for Windows developers:

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/5

> It has been very helpful to see experience with various firewalls. We
>   are very aware of the issues and are looking into it. Unfortunately,
>   this is something that will probably take some time. We did release
>   WSL as a beta knowing that there would be some issues and are working
>   hard to address things.
>
> Here's the state of the world as I know it when it comes to firewalls
>   / no network:
>
> **Outbound Traffic**
>
> **Kaspersky**: *Needs to be uninstalled* for internet access in WSL
>
> **Avast**: *Needs to be uninstalled* for internet access in WSL
>
> **Bitdefender**:
>   Firewall must be disabled to get internet access in WSL.
>
> **AVG**: Looks
>   like they have done some work in AVG 2016 (learned this on thread #475). Not certain what they have done, but it is interesting to note.
>
> **Windows Firewall**: Must have unchecked "*Outbound rules that do not
>   match a rule are denied*"
>
> **Inbound Traffic**
>
> Still looking into this one. Using WSL as a server was not one of our
>   core priorities for the Anniversary Update. It is something we want to
>   support in the future.
>
> **Ping**
>
> Ping must be run with Windows Administrator privileges We are doing a
>   little more due diligence before reaching out to the firewall
>   providers. I will also update the FAQ with more information when found
>   (have a very bare bones placeholder there now).

Comment: To clarify, I am using Bitdefender, and after disabling the firewall I am still unable to gain internet access in WSL. I have tried all of the approach/solution listed on your [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/5). None of them has worked. The only thing that I haven't done yet is uninstalling Bitdefender.

Comment: Did you set your network to "trusted"?

Comment: Yes, it was on a trusted network.

Comment: @jlliagre - I have been busy in the last 24 hours.

Comment: You do realize I don't get pinged when you make edits to your answer right, so unless I return to every single question/answer I issue a vote on myself, I wouldn't know you made an edit to your answer.  Trust me I had better things to do the check every single vote I issued yesterday to see if I wanted to reverse my vote.  Despite the fact I you pinged me after only wait 12 hours, I went ahead and reversed my vote, hopefully you have no other reason to ping me about

Answer (score 0):

In Windows firewall, add a permission/exception for the program:

C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe

And be happy.

Comment: Even after adding wsl and allowing private and public connections im still seeing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue at some point.

I updated the windows version to 2004 and allowed windows virtual machine in the firewall setting.

Things now work fine for me.